# Реально ли собрать такое на flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, grid-layout

Главное условие - не менять html-разметку старого проекта. У коде сейчас просто набор `div.col` - дивов с одиноаковым классом для всех.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и должно быть адаптивно, конечно.

Текущая верстка была на бутстрапе, от которого хотим избавиться. Выглядело примерно так:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="news__item news__item_overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="news__item news__item_left"></div>
        <div class="news__item news__item_left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="news__item news__item_left"></div>
        <div class="news__item news__item_left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="news__item news__item_top"></div>
        <div class="news__item news__item_top"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы примерную разметку предоставили.

Comment: Добавил текущуя верстку на бутстрапе

Comment: Flexbox? Не советую, в новых браузерах типо фаера все работает как надо. Но взять андроид браузеры под планш, это будет все ужасно.

Comment: Я посоветовалбы чистый css. С подсчетом обьектов, например 1=> сделать полноэкранную. Дальше четное нечетное. И просто float:left;

Comment: Можно пример, о чем речь?

Comment: @ДенисКотляров пример можете показать?

Comment: @mihdan, я думаю, что **ДенисКотляров** имел ввиду http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child

Comment: А чем имеющееся решение не нравится?

Comment: Очевидно, что там бутстрап и такой шаблон сложно через РНР строить, решения мы так и не нашли, в итоге блок переверстали совсем иначе  http://screenshot.kobzarev.com/2018-02-24-1519479998.png